# how to fix the error while downloading video

Tags: youtube-dl

When I try to download a video, I get an error:

`youtube-dl http://youtu.be/My2FRPA3Gf8`:

```
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Extracting video information
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Encrypted signatures detected.

ERROR: unable to download video
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated version of youtube-dl. Since YouTube changes its interface regularly, youtube-dl has its own update mechanism. Type

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

to update. If that does not work, feel free to [file a bug](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/new) at the youtube-dl project. Don't forget to include the full output when calling youtube-dl with `-v`, like this:

```
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', 'http://youtu.be/My2FRPA3Gf8']
[debug] Encodings: locale 'UTF-8', fs 'UTF-8', out 'UTF-8', pref: 'UTF-8'
[debug] youtube-dl version 2014.01.27.2
[debug] Python version 2.6.6 - Linux-2.6.32-274.7.1.el5.028stab095.1-x86_64-with-debian-6.0.8
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Extracting video information
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Encrypted signatures detected.
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 22, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 43, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 18, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 5, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 36, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 17, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 137, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] My2FRPA3Gf8: Downloading js player vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 136, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 135, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 134, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 133, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 160, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 140, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 84 (41.42), itag 171, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 137, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 136, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 135, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 134, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 133, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 160, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 140, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[youtube] encrypted signature length 85 (44.40), itag 171, html5 player ima-en_US-vflkClbFb
[download] Destination: Miley Cyrus - Wrecking Ball-My2FRPA3Gf8.mp4
[download] 100% of 40.76MiB in 00:04
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the video using the link which displays on the address bar of your web-browser... **[This post](http://www.geeklk.com/2011/03/download-youtube-videos-using-terminal-commands-linuxubuntu/)** may help to get to know more..

E.g.: `youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2leg8mUE9rs` instead of what you tried

Comment: Did you try with OP's specific link? I also expect some comments about copyright violations.

Comment: thanks for the response.tried using the above example..it failed too...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating it:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

should solve your problems.

Comment: why are you trying to update a package via itself. When you actually upgrade it with update manager or similar methods.